Can you set a cell range based on the number of rows in Google Sheets?
Part of my macro inserts a formula into a cell and then copies it down to by a number of rows. The number of rows changes from sheet to sheet based on the content of one of the columns. I don't want to copy it down to the bottom of the sheet as there is other content below my main table.
How do I count the number of rows in a give column (that contains content) and then apply that number to the range that I want to copy the formula down by?
This code returns the correct number of rows...
function AutoNotes3() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const lastRow = data.length;

  console.log(lastRow);

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('AW8').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula([lastRow]-2); // the -2 account for the extra content below the range that I want to exclude

  
};

I want to use that number as a reference in a range so I tried this...
function AutoNotes4() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const lastRow = data.length;

  console.log(lastRow);

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('AW8').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=VLOOKUP(B8,INDIRECT(Settings!$A$3&"!$B$8:$AW"), 48, FALSE)');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('AW8:AW&[lastRow]-2'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);

};

When I run the script it can't apply the range.

Try setting the range like this in order to get the correct string. If not it's not concatenating but trying to get literally the range AW8:AW&[lastRow]-2
.... .getRange('AW8:AW'+(lastRow-2))

Perfect! That was the syntax I was after. Thank you.
